# Not being able to parse json data to html list using ajax

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I have a news ticker which is working fine with static html data but I cant figure out how to show up dynamic data in the specified html layout. I am not being able to parse the json data into the list.

Thanks in advance.

getnews.php

```
<?php
include 'connect.php';
$return = array();
$sql = "SELECT * FROM news";
$result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
while($details = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    $details_array['date'] = $details['date'];
    $details_array['headline'] = $details['headline'];
    $details_array['content'] = $details['content'];

    array_push($return, $details_array);
}
echo json_encode($return);
?>
```

jQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type:'GET',
        url: 'getnews.php',
        success: function(data){
            var response=JSON.parse(data);
            $(function(){
                $.each(response, function(i, item){
                    $('<ul>').append($('<li>').text(item.heading));
                });
            });
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

HTML news Ticker

```
<div id="NewsTicker">
<ul>

<li><div>23rd<br>Sep</div><headline>Expandable Input</headline>
<p><news>Expandable Input is a minimal jQuery plugin to smoothly expand the width of a input filed when focused/clicked and collapse it when lose focus.</news></p>
</li>

<li><div>24th<br>Sep</div><headline>jQuery Photor Plugin</headline>
<p><news>Photor is a fast and easy jQuery plugin to create a responsive & touch-friendly full page image gallery with CSS3 transitions and transforms.</news></p>
</li>

<li><div>25th<br>Sep</div><headline>Metreaux Tables</headline>
<p><news>Metreaux Tables is a jQuery plugin to create nice, clean, themeable, andmodern Windows 8 UI Style data tables with the power of DataTables jQuery javascript library.</news></p>
</li>

</ul>
```

Comment: What's the output of `$.type( data )`? String or Object?

Comment: can you do an alert or console.log() of the var response in the JavaScript and see if the data is coming correctly from the server?

Comment: I think this link will help you understand how the append works. They show specifically how to append to a list: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_html_append

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, if you're requesting JSON with an AJAX request, you should set `dataType` to
`"json"` so that you don't have to manually parse it. I.e.,

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'getnews.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        ...
    }
});
```

As of jQuery 1.5, you should use `.done()` from for the result of
[$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#jqXHR) instead of passing
`success: ...`. I.e.,

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'getnews.php',
    dataType: 'json',
}).done(function(data) {
    ...
});
```

You were very close, but you want to put your `$.each()` call directly
inside of your *success* callback. Using `$(function() {...})` is a short cut
for `$(document).ready(function() {...})` which registers the function to be
called once the page has loaded. You should do:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'getnews.php',
    dataType: 'json'
}).done(function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(i, item) {
        ...
    });
});
```

Now, inside of your `$.each()` callback, you're creating a new `<ul>`, and
adding a child `<li>` to it, but without actually adding it to the page. It
appears to me that you intend to append each item to the `<ul>` under
`<div id="NewsTicker">`. To do that, you want to do:

```
var $newsList = $('#NewsTicker > ul');
$.each(data, function(i, item) {
    $('<li>')
        .append($('<div>').html(item.date))
        .append($('<headline>').html(item.headline))
        .append(
          $('<p>').append(
            $('<news>').html(item.content)
          )
        )
        .appendTo($newsList);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

As per understanding from the given code , I think you need to generate the same HTML structure as expected by Ticker dynamically inside your success handler.
Should be something like:

```
 $('<ul>').append("<li><div>"+item.date+"</div><headline>"+item.heading+"</headline><p><news>"+item.content+"</news></p></li>");
```

Note: Also you need to use "item.heading" not "headline"